# Why application terminates when coroutine tries to enter Dispatchers.Main?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to add coroutine that firstly sets `progressBar` visible, then asks server for data and, when it gets the data, `progressBar` is set invisible. I have read that to interact with UI my coroutine needs to operate in `Dispatcher.Main`, but when I try to set `launch(Dispatcher.Main)` whole **application terminates without an error**.

I started following tutorial from: https://www.kotlindevelopment.com/deep-dive-coroutines/. I changed a part from code shown there:

```
launch(UI) {
  progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  try {
    val userString = fetchUserString("1").await()
    val user = deserializeUser(userString).await()
    showUserData(user)
  } catch (ex: Exception) {
    log(ex)
  } finally {
    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
  }
}
```

to:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                progressBarMarkers.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                try {
                    val repository = MarkerRepository()
                    points = repository.getAllDataAsync().await()
                    }
               } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    Log.d("EXCEPTION", ex.toString())
               } finally {
                    progressBarMarkers.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
            }
```

but it didn't work. I started searching for what could be the problem and I found out that when my coroutine looks as shown below the app terminates when it reaches `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`

```
GlobalScope.launch{
        val button = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBarMarkers)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
}
```

I am still very new to Kotlin and coroutines, so maybe it is just some basic mistake, but I couldn't find the answer why the application terminates, and whats more terminates without an error

Whole coroutine is in:

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private val REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE: Int = 123
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        ShowPlacesButton.setOnClickListener {
            launch{
                val button = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBarMarkers)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main + Job()){
                    button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
        }
    }
}
```

and parts of my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1"
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
}
```

Why does the app terminate, when it reaches `Dispatcher.Main`?

Comment: Could you please post the log cat exception trace? If it's not found in Error, it might be in Verbose

Comment: `GlobalScope.launch { val button = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBarMarkers) }` -- here you run GUI code on a non-GUI thread so it crashes. Launch the coroutine in `Dispatchers.Main` and don't use `GlobalScope`. Google for "Kotlin structured concurrency" and check out the code sample in the documentation of `CoroutineScope`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you maybe have "show only selected application" enabled in logcat? Or some other sort of filter?

Because when I run your code, I get this very helpful crash:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.idunnno.test, PID: 27501
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher is missing. Add dependency providing the Main dispatcher, e.g. 'kotlinx-coroutines-android'
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.missing(MainDispatchers.kt:73)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.isDispatchNeeded(MainDispatchers.kt:54)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedKt.resumeCancellable(Dispatched.kt:373)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:25)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:152)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.idunnno.daggertest.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:27)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:32)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:233)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:742)
```

The basic fix is to add this line to your Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1"
```

Some other notes:

1. You don't want to use `findViewById` inside a click listener.  You should be performing that task once - probably in `onCreate` - and then saving it off to a class-level property.
2. You don't really need to be using a `launch` inside that click listener.
3. If you're going to use coroutines, then the class should probably just implement `CoroutineScope`.  This means you don't have to create a new context or use `GlobalScope` every time you want to use `launch` or `async`.

Comment: I actually had this filter on my logcat, but even after turning it off no error was shown. But the addition of the line you suggested solved my problem!

Comment: Why？Is coroutine default main thread is different from android's main thread?

Comment: @Bill coroutines don't actually know what a "main thread" is.  The Default and IO dispatchers just use pools from executors.  In order to provide `Dispatchers.Main`, the coroutines library needs to use a service loader to get our `Looper.mainLooper()`.

Coroutines aren't just for Android, though, and other platforms have different solutions.  

So in the core `kotlinx.coroutines` module, `Dispatchers.Main` is effectively abstract.  In order to use it, you need to add one of the artifacts which provides an implementation like `kotlinx.coroutines-android`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your proguard file

-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.android.* {*;}

Answer (score 0):

This is the same error I got when I was using Retrofit to fetch some data from the internet inside the coroutine Scope.

The fix was pretty simple which was turning the internet on in my testing physical device.